# How to group an object by its associated model when using a has_many :through relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I am working on an application that helps a local restaurant track the hours worked each day. The user enters data through a model called a "Checkout" at the end of each shift. They select an employee that is associated with a `has_many :through => employment`, where the employment model is a join table. Granted, `Checkout` is a confusing term, but that is the DSL that the restaurant wanted to use.

How do you group the hours worked by each employee on a given day? There might be 2 checkouts in the database for that employee on that day – one from lunch and one from dinner.

I want to create a list of hours that each employee worked on a given day when their hours from that day might be stored in separate checkouts in the database.

```
Today's Date
Joe Employee
Hours worked: 12

Jill Employee
Hours worked: 4

etc.
```

How do I group the checkouts by employee when they are not an attribute on the checkouts model, but rather are an association through my employment model? Essentially, I'm trying to do something like this in my reports helper:

```
def checkouts_today
  current_user.checkouts.where( :date => Date.today )
end

def employee_hours_today
  checkouts_today.where( :employment => Employee.find_by(id: params[:id]) ).sum(:hours)
end
```

But I can't get it to work with the has_many :through association. I can only figure out how to total all hours from that day, not the total hours per employee.

Here are the relevant files:

- models/checkout.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/a2a0578adaf8841d4d5e
- models/employee.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/2df5e7fb7db0ac0f602c
- models/employment.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/d3a028b6effe5f245b2a
- helpers/reports_helper.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/e2503188bb26df64ad20
- view/payroll_processing.html.erb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/868b1272128e75dc60d0
- db/schema.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/f9ce764d16161b7b3017

**Update:**
I can loop through each employee and display their checkouts with this:

```
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>
    <% if employee.checkouts.present? %>
        <p><%= employee.full_name %></p>

        <% employee.checkouts.each do |checkout| %>
            <%= checkout.date %>
            <%= checkout.shift %>
            <%= checkout.hours %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But, I can't figure out how to sum their hours and display and return it in one block. It returns each checkout for each day under each employee's name. It also seems like this kind of logic should not be in the view.

Comment: Should I be using the group method to do this? Or loop through each employee and display their checkout hours?

Comment: you need to display in one line Name of the employee and total hours of his checkouts?

Comment: I just need to calculate the hours an employee worked on a given day. But there might be multiple checkouts with that employee on any given day. The employee and checkout are associated with a has_many :through. I edited the original post because the formatting was making it confusing.

Comment: and why .sum(:hours) it's not working?

Comment: I mean you get all checkouts for a day for one employee and then just sum hours of those checkouts. Would like to play in your console via Teamviewer, who knows, I might solve it :)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm having trouble doing. I can't figure out how to scope the hours worked to one employee. I can only figure out how to sum all the hours from a day. I'm also able to loop through all the checkouts individually for each day on the Employee index action, but I'm not able to group them by each individual employee. Can't do Teamviewer right now, but I appreciate the offer and help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34726/discussion-between-rmagnum2002-and-lee-mcalilly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st method**

in **checkout.rb**:

```
scope :checkouts_today, -> {where(date: Date.today)}
```

in your view or controller:

```
employee.checkouts.checkouts_today.sum(:hours)
```

---

**2nd method**

in **employee.rb**

```
has_many :today_checkouts, class_name: "Checkout", conditions: {date: Date.today}
```

in your view or controller:

`employee.today_checkouts.sum(:hours)`

Not sure the 2nd way would work as you have a join table to get the relation between `Employee` and `Checkout`. As we discussed in chat, you can drop the join table, in your case I don't see where you'll need it, give your app more space.

Comment: rmagnum2002, I'm still trying to sort this out. Don't worry, I'll definitely accept your answer, but how would you do this same thing if I moved this into a "Reports" model. It seems that this should be extracted out of the employees or checkouts to a new model for generating reports like "Employee hours worked today", etc.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34726/discussion-between-rmagnum2002-and-lee-mcalilly

Comment: See chat above for full transcript of how this question was solved. Thanks to rmagnum2002